# Rails - creating multiple records of one model in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose we have a User model with name attribute. 
I want to create a form with multiple text fields to create multiple records in the database. I was able to accomplish this using form_tag but is there a way to do it using form_for?

Comment: You can make another model called UserName and make multiple nested forms inside your form_for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with `form_for` is possible but since this is really not a form that relates to a single model instance, you really should stick to `form_tag`

To do it as `form_for` every name will have to be an attribute.

You could do (in your model)...

```
attr_accessor :name1, :name2, :name3
```

This will let the additional names be accepted even though they're not columns in the db table.

Then in your create method...

```
def create
  %i(name name1 name2 name3).each |this_name|
    User.create(name: user_params(this_name)) if user_params(this_name).present?
  end
end


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :name1, :name2, :name3)
end
```

Comment: I will stick to my form_tag since it seems easier to maintain for me. Thanks Steve!